# System blows up during install

Tags: tensorflow

I downloaded a clean copy of python 35.3

Tried installing tensorflow per the instructions.  It did not work.  The method is described as https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows.  Here is the result.

```
Python 3.5.3 (v3.5.3:1880cb95a742, Jan 16 2017, 16:02:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

I also tried pip and eliminating the upgrade term.  All syntax out on install.

What am I missing?

Comment: running the test program gets messages about c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you entered the `pip3 install …` command at the interactive Python prompt. `pip3` is the name of a program to run, and not a command in the Python language itself.

Instead you should enter this command at a Windows command prompt (e.g. the prompt you get by running `cmd.exe` or "Command Prompt" in the Start menu).

Comment: I will try  it.  Thanks

Comment: tensorflow installed.  Tested the install per the website.  Here is what I got.

Comment: What did you get? (Perhaps best to update the question with any log messages that were printed....)